# How can I alter the value field in a raster?

Tags: arcpy, raster, fields-attributes, topography

I'm using ArcGIS. I have a raster with angles in the value field. But the value field is type long integer. I would like to change it to float. Is that possible?
Some more details:
I've started with a DEM, and created two arrays with from it using numpy. The first array is the DEM source of data, and the second is the target array where I store de processed cells. I'm generating a topographic exposure raster.

My issue is that the value field from the original DEM is a long integer, therefore not suitable to storage decimal values. So, my question is how to change that value field type to float. This is done in python.

---

The way I solved this is by multiplying the angles (final data to store) by 1000000, so the value field store all the numbers that I need. I find this a cheesy trick. Is there a better/more 'elegant' solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can multiply your numpy array by 1.0 and this will change the type of pixel to float.

```
newarray = oldarray*1.0
new_raster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(newarray)
```

Comment: Thanks @radouxju. This was the kind of answer I needed. Let me try it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of changing data type for a raster is to use the [Copy Raster](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#/Copy_Raster/001700000094000000/) tool where you can change the pixel type parameter to float 32.